# Store first value of http request with rxjs but keep doing httprequest

Tags: javascript, observer-pattern, rxjs

With RXJS library :
I need to store values from the FIRST http request, but keep doing other http request on demand.

I have done this code so far, and that is working. But I think there is a more elegant way.

```
const Rx = require("rxjs");
let numHttp = 0;
const httpRequest = () => {
    let a = [];
    numHttp = numHttp + 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        a.push({ num: i, http: numHttp });
    };
    return new Rx.BehaviorSubject(a)
        .do(a => {
            console.log("antoher http request");
            if (getC.getValue() === undefined) {
                getC.next(a)
            }
        })
        // .do(n => { if (getB.) getB.next(n) })
}
const getB = () => {
    const a = new Rx.BehaviorSubject();
    return a
};
getC = getB();
httpRequest().subscribe(d => d);
httpRequest().subscribe(d => d);
getC.subscribe(data => console.log('cache', data))
httpRequest().subscribe(d => d);
httpRequest().subscribe(d => d);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to solve the problem since the question is not providing all the necessary details.

Assuming you have a factory for your Http observable (call it `createHttpObservable()`) you may do something like this:

```
const observable = createHttpObservable()

  // Share the stream of events across all the subscribers.
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount()

  // Use `.scan()` against event stream (similarly to how we `.reduce()` against an array).
  .scan(
    (history, currentValue, valueIndex) => {
      history.push({ num: valueIndex, httpNum: currentValue });
      return history;
    },
    []
  )

  // Take the last event from the `history`
  .map(history => history[history.length - 1].httpNum)

  // Arbitrarily use `.do` for side effects.
  .do(console.log);


// Subscribe wherever you need.
observable.subscribe();
observable.subscribe();
observable.subscribe();
```

Here's a related, but not quite the same exact [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/msvVSs?p=preview).

You can have more custom logic in the `.scan()` block, but frankly, I have no idea what are you trying to achieve and why is the first Http request's results are of any special interest.